# SelectedIndex causing a crash although it is being set to zero

Tags: c#, exception, listbox

The code is in a `ListBox` in a `Silverlight` application but I think the issue is not really specific to that so here is the code:

```
    MyListBox processListBox = (sender as MyListBox);
    if (processListBox != null)
    {
        if (processListBox.SelectedItem == null)
            processListBox.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }
```

so it is crashing on

```
processListBox.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

with an `IndexOutOfRange exception` and the weird thing is that when I hover over the `SelectedIndex` it is showing **-1**  so let's say for some crazy reason the value is -1 but still we are setting it to zero so why it still crashes?

Comment: have you tried putting break points in the code and stepping through the code.. why not check the code against the `Selected.Index == -1`

Comment: @Sybren can you please explain more and your suggestion for fix? thanks

Comment: @Bohn read the suggestion of MethodMan

Comment: @Bohn also use MessageBox.Show(processListBox.Items.Count.ToString()) to see if the ListBox contains items.  It could still be not null and have no items. What event are you handling?

Comment: A value of -1 means "no selection".  And you better keep it that way because clearly you don't have any items in the listbox so you can't select the first item.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it's that simple? *If* your ListBox contains **no** items, then setting

```
processListBox.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

will throw an `IndexOutOfRange exception` because there is nothing to select...